# Chisel HDL for CPLDs

Tags: hdl, chisel

Is it possible to use the [Chisel HDL](https://chisel.eecs.berkeley.edu/)  with a CPLD? If yes, have you
tried it, could you share experience please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Chisel generate Verilog code and the CPLD accept Verilog for synthesis, yes it's possible.
I tested it with a CoolRunnerII from Xilinx. That works well.